# JavaFX: Is there any way to show images in a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to show images in a `TextArea`, just like a `div` with `contentEditable` in HTML.
I do NOT wan't a background image.
For example:
[image: <code>div</code> with <code>contentEditable</code> in HTML]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an image in textarea for JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43307781/how-to-set-an-image-in-textarea-for-javafx)

Comment: @aristotll
Maybe it's the only way to solve my quesion. 
But I want the images are editable just like texts.

Answer (score 0):

The only possbility I see is by adding it as Background of the TextArea. For example via css with `fx-background-image:url`

Answer (score 0):

try to add the textarea and the image in a same group like :

```
Textarea text = new Textarea();
ImageView img= new ImageView ();

Group group = new Group();

group.getChildren().add(img);
group.getChildren().add(text);
```

Comment: It almost solve my quesion!
But i still not found any way to remove the image just like HTML

Comment: i m glad i helped ! can u explain more?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in JavaFX
Try using Webview rather than Text Area.
You can display both text and images in an html page, which can be loaded in Webview

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question fully, but in my answer I created `TextFlow` and add both the `TextArea` and the `ImageView` to it. When you type into `TextArea`, `TextFlow` is updated to include new text as well as the image. After that `TextFlow` is displayed in `VBox` with `TextArea` and `Image`.

**Source code:**

```
public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPrefSize(400, 200);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("file:C:/Users/FAbdu/Downloads/java.png"));
        imageView.setFitWidth(200);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
        textFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text(textArea.getText()), imageView);

        textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            textFlow.getChildren().clear();
            textFlow.getChildren().addAll(new Text(newValue), imageView);
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textArea, textFlow);
        root.setCenter(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]